# How to bybass sql injection error in Javascript

Tags: javascript, sql, oracle, parameters, code-injection

I am getting sql injection error while trying to run the below code in javascript. I am trying to see a way to update this using parameter or some place holders to bybass the injection error but I am not sure. The issue is that due to the fact that to create a secure web site, variable concatinated as 'i' below could be replaced with a parameter so that the site will not be vulnerable when selecting records from the database. I have seen fixes in php on this injection just like the one in the below article bit trying to see how to work around this in Javascript. In the below 'i' could be 'name'. That is, Select name as overday_disolay from country, which takes the name that a user types in the form and replace the place holder 'i' with the 'name' given by user. Article below explains more but it is not a fix in javascript(I cannot use same fucntion used in the artile so I need a work around in Javascript). Injection error is thrown by the application.

https://www.acunetix.com/websitesecurity/sql-injection/

```
 function getUnionDataSql()
{
    var sql = "";

    sql += " SELECT DISTINCT "+ i+ " AS overday_display FROM country UNION"
```

}

Comment: Bypass? Why not fix the code?

Comment: Where is the JavaScript executing? Node.js?

Comment: @DanMcGhan The script is embedded in xml and outputs to jsp as the application that I am using is based on Java. Not sure if you have heard of 'Archibus' before. Yes is I still can use Java to run the sql statement and call the java class as workflow but this time the script is in javascript and I just want to be able to get a function in javascript which allows me to use parameter instead of the variable in my sql statement

Comment: Have a look at this and let me know if this answers your question: https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/issues/946 It's for Node.js, but the same rules apply everywhere.

Comment: @DanMcGhan thanks for this. This could have helped but I finally figured out a way out by updating  a configuartion in the application internally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this. There are 2 options as allowed in the internal application. One is to use substring or use parameter inplace of the above variables. The other is to configure reserved words in the application.

Answer (score 0):

You should not directly pass variables into your SQL statements. This will allow the user to insert malicious code inside your SQL statement.

Therefore, you should use your SQL package's escape functions ahead to avoid this.

Comment: Thanks Marvin, I understand I cannot pass variables like that and that is exactly why I am asking if there is a function to be used in oracle within Javascript. The link above shows how its handled in PHP. This link also shows fixes in java and other 3 languages but I am looking for a way to do that in JavaScript pointing to oracle DB